# Draw draggable/adjustable rectangle on image based on PREDEFINED COORDINATES in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, bounding-box

I calculate the rectangular bounding box coordinates for objects in my matlab code ([xmin ymin width height]). But the coordinates might not be precise. Then, I want to draw the box on the image and modify that by dragging the box and/or adjusting the borders. I tried to use imrect and imcrop, but those functions do not draw the **draggable/adjustable rectangle** on image, based on **predefined coordinates**. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [imrect](https://se.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html). It works much like the imcrop rectangle but you can set an initial position and get the current position by calling getPosition.